# Strange Error while installing MySQL .Net connector 6.8.3

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

[image]

I'm already installing version 6.8.3 but it asks me to install a version greater that 6.7... 
I just don't understand why this is happening...
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and trying to install this latest connector for MySql to get Entity Framework to work.
any clue? Any Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even after going through a pile of bugs posted in MySQL forum for the same issue, I couldn't solve it. Finally I used a third party application uninstaller "REVO Uninstaller". You might want to try your preferred one in this case, I just googled for a good uninstaller and it said REVO that why I chose it. I did a full uninstall including registry entries and then tried to install the new version of MySQL Connector 6.8.3 and I succeed. This is how I made it. I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same problem.  When you install choose 'custom', then deselect the option to install web providers.  Once I did that my install completed without error.

Comment: that's not a solution apoc76, I do need to install Web Providers also.